# installing Google App Engine Tools into Eclipse (ADT)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, adt

Basicly seems like this should be straightforward. I get this error when attempting to install from http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3:

[image]

What should I do to make this install work?

I am following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse#Installing_the_Google_Plugin_for_Eclipse)

Comment: My eclipse ADT is 4.2 have you tried the Juno version https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely not happy with your version. Change the URL to http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 and it will work.